# What was that book that listed all the rich/influential people and defined socioeconomic status for many Americans?

Tags: united-states

Americans in the upper-elite class specifically, I think. It was a semi-annual publication, and was significant before WWII, perhaps even before WWI.

Comment: So it's something that's no longer published?

Comment: @SteveBird no I dont think so. It definitely doesn't have a role in modern society.

Comment: Forbes has a [yeary list](https://www.forbes.com/forbes-400/)

Comment: Research [***Who's Who***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_Who)

Comment: Strictly speaking, it didn't define socioeconomic status; it defined a cultural institution known as "polite society".  Conflating these two terms perpetrates the exclusionary presumptions of the social register and implies that all non-members are equal in socioeconomic status, which would not lead to a good understanding of socioeconomic status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh I found it: [the social register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Register). I've edited my question to reflect accurate information.